# Can I connect Battery positive terminal directly to MCU ADC input Pin?

Tags: microcontroller, battery-operated

[image]MCU is powered directly from 3 V battery and I am using ADC input of MCU to monitor the battery voltage to detect low battery situation. I have got good inputs on this site(I need to monitor the battery voltage very rarely and this is a battery powered board and designed for long life) to use a NFET, PFET and a resistive divider circuit to connect the signal MCU. Why shouldn’t I directly connect the battery voltage to ADC Pin? Perhaps with a series resistor.

EDIT:
MCU has internal 1.45 V standard reference for ADC. The 1.45 V can be one of possible ADC input and also can be used as Reference voltage for ADC.
From the safety aspects, can I connect battery directly to MCU ADC input Pin?

Comment: If your 1.45V reference can be directed as an *input* to the ADC, you can use the battery as the reference and just do the math to figure out its voltage.

Comment: @Alex This question led me to your answer towards reducing component count (cost and space) and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main things you need to figure out are the ADC input voltage range and the ADC reference voltage.  Some microcontrollers use the microcontroller power supply voltage as the ADC reference voltage.  In this case, the ADC output will be something like 1024*Vin/Vcc for a 10 bit ADC.  The ADC input range on these is generally anything within the voltage rails.  Anything outside the rails would have to be divided down.  It rather defeats the usefulness of the ADC if it is supplied with the battery voltage as all ADC measurements will then be in relation to the unknown battery voltage.  Measuring the battery voltage this way is completely futile as you will always get the same result out of the ADC, independent of battery voltage (ADCcode = 1024*Vbat/Vbat = 1024).  Other microcontrollers will have a separate reference for the ADC that is independent of the supply voltage.  In this case, the input range is more limited, generally GND to Vref, which could be as low as 1V.  In this case, you would have to divide down the power supply voltage for measurement.

Now, I don't know what controller you are using, so I am going to provide some possible solutions for either case.

For a microcontroller like the Atmel AVR series that uses the power supply as a voltage reference, what I would suggest doing is measuring a fixed reference voltage with the ADC input and then compute what the power supply voltage is from that.  No need to divide anything down in this case.  You can get quite accurate shunt references around 1 to 1.2 volts in SOT-23, and you can use a PMOS to turn it off when not in use.  Compute the battery voltage 'backwards' with Vbat = Vref * 1024/ADCcode.

For a microcontroller like the Atmel AVR XMEGA series that uses an internal reference, you will have to divide down the power supply voltage to something within the input range, which is 0 to 1 V with the internal reference.  You can use a PMOS transistor to disconnect the divider when not in use, or you can use very large (~1M) resistors and a smoothing capacitor on the ADC input pin.  The smoothing capacitor is generally a good idea for power supply measurements anyway as it will reduce high frequency noise as well as allowing the ADC sample and hold cap to charge up quickly.  Compute the battery voltage the normal way with Vbat = ADCcode /1024 * Vref.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The MCU has 1.45 V standard internal reference for ADC and also it can use supply as Vref. As mentioned in the post, I only meed to detect low battery voltage (2.1 V) in my case..

Comment: Removed comment as i understood your point little slowly

Comment: can you please comment on safety aspects of connecting ADC directly to MCU?

Comment: Well, if the internal reference is 1.45 volts, then you generally cannot measure anything larger than this with the ADC.  You probably will not damage the ADC so long as the input is within the supply rails; however both a full battery and a low battery will read as 'off scale high'.  Which is not useful for you.  So you will need to add a voltage divider of some sort on the ADC input in order to get a useful reading.

Comment: the 1.45 V can be one of the ADC inputs, and hence sampling directly the 1.45 V standard reference with respect to the MCU-VCC will help in estimating the battery life(reverse calculation) as explained by you in the answer.  Coming back to my question, can I connect it now directly to the MCU ADC Pin. is there any safety precaution to be taken care of?  Inputs will never be higher than the ADC range.

Comment: Well, check the ratings on your microcontroller for what the ADC range is.  Generally voltages between Vcc and GND should not cause damage, though you should check the datasheet to make sure.  If you can connect the internal reference to an ADC input pin, then you need to make sure that using Vcc as the external reference is acceptable.  The datasheet should tell you.

Comment: the Range of built in MCU ADC and Battery Power maximum voltage are all in safer margins. I think I didn't come from the right angle to resolve my basic doubt. All the electrical specs are proper. If I connect External battery voltage to MCU ADC Pin, will there be any damage, specifically when MCU is in deep sleep mode, sleep mode etc. For normal operations it is totally acceptable.

Comment: What specific MCU are you using?

Comment: R5F10WLFAFA,I have added ADC snap for quick reference

Comment: Well, that's perfect, then.  All you need to do is set the ADC Vref to Vcc in the configuration registers and then measure the voltage of the internal reference.  I don't believe you will need any external connections to the ADC inputs for this to work.

Comment: No series resistors of PFETs? Will add one small capacitor for sure

Comment: You do not need to connect anything to the ADC inputs at all. The battery voltage will be sensed on the power input pins, and the reference is routed to the ADC internally.

Comment: The Reference is not routed to ADC internally. It is only to use as positive side reference of the ADC. I still need to connect VCC to one of the ADC input pins or **AREFP** pin. Am I right?

Comment: There is a mux on the internal adc reference that can be used to select Vcc as the reference. This will use the voltage on the device power pins as the reference. Then there is another mux to select the input, and this mux can be set to the 1.45v internal reference. No external connections are required.

Comment: Pls reply if you have time: I have MCu powered up with unregualted battery (3 V). I had thought i can use internal reference of 1.45 V to measure the battery voltage. But, Just now came to know that, i cannot use internal voltage reference when battery voltage falls below 2.4 V :(  MCU can operate down to 1.8 V. Now, I will not be able to measure battery voltage less than 2.4 V. Any solutions to measure battery voltage in this case?

Comment: Well, I think you're going to have to use an external reference, then.  You can use the same trick, except put the external reference on one of the ADC input pins.  You should be able to power the reference from a spare GPIO pin as well so you can turn it off when not in use.  No need for a discrete transistor as the current draw should be well within the capabilities of a GPIO pin.